# RSA Encryption using aspnet_regiis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, rsa

Hi I tried to encrypt my connectionString in webconfig using aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication"

I want to ask which key is used to encrypt my connection string, because here I ommited the provider parameter. Is there anyway to check it?

Thanks before

Comment: You should see the provider in your encrypted config file. For example: <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">

Comment: Okay I see, if I ommited the provider ConnectionString will be <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">.

But if i specified the provider, the connection string will be <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="MyProvider">

And how can I decrypt my connection string if I ommited the provider?

I use [this](http://http://pastebin.com/KmYQCctg) to encrypt my connection string. But it will error, if I ommited the provider when I encrypt my connection string.

Answer (score 0):

to decrypt your web.config you just need to use aspnet_regiis again with -pd key:

```
aspnet_regiis -pd connectionStrings -app /MyApplication
```